# How to mark message for deletion by key in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to mark message specified by key for deletion, but the only script I know for deleting message is `kafka-delete-records.sh`. However it works with offsets and deletes **all messages before the offset**, which is not suitable for me. Is it possible to delete **only** message with specified offset or key from the topic?

Answer (score 2):

Kafka isn't really designed to be used like that. It's an immutable event log. Depending on what it is you're logging, you'd maybe log the opposite operation of one that you previously logged if you wanted to negate it.

Here is more info on how you can look at deleting messages using compacted topics and tombstone (null) messages: https://www.confluent.io/blog/handling-gdpr-log-forget/